# Object pushed to array overites

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got strange thing, it's probably simple but I can't find a solution for it. Here is part of the code:

```
$counter = 0;
$autoload_view_instace = new Logic_InvoiceCostData;

$sub_view_cost = array();
foreach($invoceCostData as $data)
{
    $counter++;
    $parm = $autoload_view_instace->edit_view_data($autoload_view, $data, $counter);
    array_push( $sub_view_cost, $parm);
}
```

The loop calls the `edit_view_data` method which returns an object with some values. That object should be placed at the end of the array in each iteration without changing values of objects previously added. But after each iteration, all objects in the array have the same value as the newly added object.

Comment: try $sub_view_cost[]=$parm ; instead and see if it works. However , it is advisable  in php manual that  Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Comment: Tried and same result. Checked every variable in that method and it seems ok it returns what I want.

Comment: try unsetting `$parm` at the end of `foreach` loop as `unset($parm)`

Comment: Perhaps the object returned by `edit_view_data` is the same object each time, and you're unwittingly modifying one instance multiple times. Try `var_dump($parm)` each time; the first line should be `object(className)#123` or similar - does the `#123` change each time, or is it the same?

Comment: Ayeits the same object

Comment: OK, then you'll need to make sure you return a new object from your method each time.

Comment: Are you by any chance returning a variable reference from your method?

Answer (score 0):

apparently the array_push syntax is correct.. and it should work .. however you can do the same thing  using. 
    $sub_view_cost[]=$parm ;

and make sure each time $parm get the correct value